# Converting a CRUD JSP application to be used in CQ5 (OSGi)

Tags: java, jsp, osgi, aem

I have a very simple CRUD application built using JSP. The application simply shows a list of words can be modified by the user.

I want this application to be used inside CQ5. I am new to CQ5 so I'm not sure how complicated this is. From the documentation I've read it seems the JSP application needs to be converted to OSGi module but I haven't found any documentation that shows how the transformation should look and additionally how to actually install this module in CQ5.

I would appreciate any help or links that can point to towards getting started

Answer (score 0):

CQ does support JSP scripts, but its storage model (JCR and Apache Sling Resources) is different from relational databases for example.

The [Sling in 15 minutes](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/getting-started/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html) tutorial shows how to "wire" scripts in a CQ or Sling application, it uses a .esp server-side javascript example but you can replace that with your JSP. If your list of words comes from the script that should run as is.

If your JSP gets data from something else, best might be to import that data in the CQ content repository.

Comment: Thats great. the tutorial will help a lot. However, I'm still confused as to how I actually run my bundle in CQ? Will my OSGi application create a JAR...if so, how do I upload that jar to CQ so it can be used there?

Comment: I discovered there is a "CRX Package Manager" that allows to upload my own "packages". Is that where my JSP application (converted to OSGi) would go?

Comment: You might package your JSP code, or its conversion to OSGi bundles, into a CQ content package. You can also just put your JSP scripts in the right places (as per the Sling tutorial linked to above) to have CQ execute them.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are doing, I'm not sure you need to create an OSGi bundle (at least not exclusively). What you really want is to implement a CQ/AEM component that has your JSPs. You create the component. Then create a node (in CQ/AEM, this is usually a cq:Page) that references the sling:resourceType of the component you just created. This allows you to use [Sling Resource Resolution](http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/07/cheatsheet.html) to your advantage.

If you set up your component to be able to resolve all appropriate requests, you can then make requests to your node that uses your component as its resource type.

That said, if you have other classes that your JSPs use, you will need to include them in an OSGi bundle. For example, you may have code that interfaces with a database somewhere. The easiest way to deploy a bundle (assuming you already have it compiled correctly) is to add it to a directory under /apps/some-app/install. AEM automatically watches these folders for bundles and registers them. I think you can also do it in the OSGi console (/system/console), but this is a more backdoor operation.

In its simplest form, deploying your JSPs and bundle to the system can/should be done with Package Manager. You can also use VLT, but that's more lower level and more difficult. Ideally, you would deploy your project through Maven, which would use the Package Manager REST API.

Adobe provides an [archetype for creating and deploying AEM projects](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/aem-how-tos/development/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html) with Maven. Very helpful.